# What are obsolete effects?

Tags: premiere

I'm trying to make an animated slideshow in Premiere Pro, and the examples I've found on the net all use the motion effect. However I noticed that it doesn't do anything, and I noticed it's in the obsolete folder. There are a bunch of other effects in that folder, does that mean that they don't work anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I think it means that they've been replaced by other in house effects made by Adobe which work better (ie less processing/rendering needed to create the same effect).  Adobe tends to keep the old versions around for backwards compatibility in case you need to open an old project.

This link is to After Effects, but it's the same issue:
https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/obsolete-effects.html